# How can I make sure my refactoring doesn't change the code's flow?

Tags: java, refactoring, code-analysis

I am refactoring some Java code, my intention is not to change behavior/flow at all but just to clean it up, divide it into methods, etc.

What I would like to do in the end is to make sure my changes are indeed only aesthetic and that no behavior/flow is changed.

I understand this can be "achieved" by writing comprehensive unit tests, but I'm wondering whether there is some Java code analysis utility I can use to compare the flow of the code before my changes and after, since theoretically it sounds to me like it's possible.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you don't have tests you're not really refactoring, just making changes and hoping for the best.

Comment: No. Write the tests. You can continue to use them for all your future refactorings too, not simply the one you are concerned with now, so it will be far from a sunk cost (until, that is, you decide to delete the code).

Comment: @AndyTurner A sunk cost is just a cost which is incurred and is not recoverable. All time spent on anything is a sunk cost. We cannot rewind time. Perhaps you mean a net loss?

Answer (score 5):

> since theoretically it sounds to me like it's possible

Not at all. What you are asking for is a variation of the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). You are basically asking: can I programmatically decide whether two programs behave identically, processing whatever arbitrary input.

Of course, *one* might work around the theoretical impossibilities here, for example by defining a set of "valid" inputs. In the end, that is what people do using **unit tests**.

But in that very generic sense: can I decide if two programs always do the exact same thing, I am pretty sure: you can rewrite that problem into something that resembles the halting problem, and as said: that one can **not** be solved. Not now, and not in 1000 years.

Comment: I like the analogy - perfect!